# cp: missing file operand

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I kept a cp command in alias command to take backup of a file if we remove any file using rm command.But, got the error as cp:missing operand

```
Example:
   $alias rm1='cp $@ -t ./backup  &&   rm $@'
   $rm1 arrays.sh
```

output:
       cp: missing file operand
       Try 'cp --help' for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Aliases don't take parameters. Use a function instead:

```
rm1 () {
    cp "$@" -t ./backup && rm "$@"
}
```

Note that quoting of `$@` is needed if the file names contain whitespace.